# How to inline all file's contents based on a path in an s expression

Tags: vim

I know nothing about vimscripting so I am struggling with creating a function to do the following:

I have some s expressions that can be nested with the following syntax:

```
(this::is::the::path word1 word2 (another::expresion words words)
 (yet::another::expresion
                words words)
)
```

And a path `/home/workspace`.
The first s-expression corresponds to a file at /home/workspace/this/is/the/path

What I want to do is look at all of the lines like those s-expressions that I have visually selected and replace their call with the contents of the file at that path and do that recursively.

Don't worry too much about the syntax of the files that I will be inlining. I just need to know how to do the inlining and pattern matching etc. in terms of vim calls. You can make some assumptions if anything seems too vague, please just state them.

Comment: Do you want `:h read`? (Is the path really separated by colons?)

Comment: The path in the file is colon separated but on the filesystem it is / separated

Comment: read seems to be somewhat helpful but ideally this would all be done in a function I just don't really know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I could attack it like this:

```
:cd /home/workspace
:%s#(\zs\w\+\(::\w\+\)\+#\=join(readfile(substitute(submatch(0), '::', '/', 'g')), '\n')#g
```

#### Explanation

- replace all matches of the filespec expression `\w\+\(::\w\+\)\+` with `:help :sub-replace-expr`
- the filespec is in `submatch(0)`
- transform `::` into `/` via `substitute()`
- read in the file contents via `readfile()`
- concatenate all lines with newline characters via `join()`